# Why can’t I have a <table> inside an <h2>?

Tags: html, markup, specifications

I would like to understand what is wrong with this:

```
<body>
    <h2>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Text</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </h2>
</body>
```

Validator complains:
document type does not allow element "table" here; missing one of "object", "ins", "del", "map", "button" start-tag

Further explanation says:

> The mentioned element is not allowed to appear in the context in which you've placed it; the other mentioned elements are the only ones that are both allowed there and can contain the element mentioned. This might mean that you need a containing element, or possibly that you've forgotten to close a previous element.
>
> One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put a block-level element (such as "`<p>`" or "`<table>`") inside an inline element (such as "`<a>`", "`<span>`",or "`<font>`").

Both h2 and table are block level so the last comment does not seem to apply. I want a table with h2 sized elements that is all... What is the right way to tell table to use the same size that h2 uses?

Thanks!

Comment: You can have a table inside a header. Remove the <h2> tags and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

CSS. Tables are simply not allowed inside headings, since it makes no semantic sense. Have you ever seen a book chapter whose title was a table? Don't use HTML semantic tags for appearance; style them yourself.

It doesn't matter whether `table` is block or inline by CSS, only what the HTML DTD says they are. Look [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6): only "flow" elements are allowed into `td`. Follow the link to see the definition of "flow": you'll see it's "inline" or "block". You can continue to follow those links down, until you find that, e.g. `sub` is fine, as is `span`... but you won't find `table`.

Also - tables are not even `display: block` - they have their own layout value, `display: table`. Not that it matters.

Comment: Mostly same, yes. `font-size` and `font-weight`, certainly.

Comment: Thanks!  I wish the validator message was as informative.  However, it is not right for the language to say that tables do not make sense as headings.  That should be up to the user.  I think I did not understand that h1-6 are semantical, I thought they are a convenient shorthand for sizes.

Comment: Off topic: how to include text with html code in questions and comments?  I used 4 space indents for lack of better to prevent interpretation of tags.  But that resulted in colored format due to quotes.

Comment: Your delusions are no concern of the validator :P Seriously though, fifteen years ago no-one gave a flying squirrel as to whether the HTML validated or not, and CSS didn't even exist before that. Everyone used HTML for formatting. Nowadays the best practices are clearly defined: HTML is semantic as much as possible, CSS is visual, JS provides action. (As to your SO formatting question, start lines with `">"` for quoting purposes. Use backticks to surround an inline piece of code: \`<foo>\` gives `<foo>`. And SO won't interpret your tags in any case.)

Comment: Re: SO formatting. I copied the error message verbatim from the validator page: (such as "`<p>`" or "`<table>`") and I saw only the quotes. (I used quotes as you suggested just now.)

Comment: @Matyas: here’s Stack Overflow’s guide to formatting code: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

CSS is the appropriate way to change the size of HTML elements. HTML isn’t designed to be used to create visual effects.

There’s no way in CSS to specifically tell a `<table>` to be whatever size `<h2>`s are.

However, you can tell tables and h2s to both be one specific size, e.g.:

```
h2,
table {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

You could also use Chrome’s Web Inspector (or similar tools in other browsers) to check what the default  styles are, and apply the relevant ones to your table. These default styles might vary between browsers though.

As for why you can’t have a table inside an `<h2>` tag, I’m not sure off the top of my head if the HTML spec offers rationales for its nesting rules, but `<h2>`s are meant to mark up headings, i.e. relatively short pieces of text that describe a section of a document.

It’s difficult to imagine how a table would be an appropriate heading.