# how do I prepend data to a specific h2 tag?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, csv

I have an ajax script that loads data from a csv file. However, I am having a hard time prepending it to a specific h2 tag.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    <script>
$.ajax({
  url: 'csv_data.csv',
  dataType: 'text',
}).done(successFunction);

function successFunction(data) {
  var allRows = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
  var table = '<table>';
  for (var singleRow = 0; singleRow < allRows.length; singleRow++) {
    if (singleRow === 0) {
      table += '<thead>';
      table += '<tr>';
    } else {
      table += '<tr>';
    }
    var rowCells = allRows[singleRow].split(',');
    for (var rowCell = 0; rowCell < rowCells.length; rowCell++) {
      if (singleRow === 0) {
        table += '<th>';
        table += rowCells[rowCell];
        table += '</th>';
      } else {
        table += '<td>';
        table += rowCells[rowCell];
        table += '</td>';
      }
    }
    if (singleRow === 0) {
      table += '</tr>';
      table += '</thead>';
      table += '<tbody>';
    } else {
      table += '</tr>';
    }
  } 
  table += '</tbody>';
  table += '</table>';
  $('body').append(table);
}
</script>
```

Here is my csv file:

```
Name,City,Country
William,Yamrat,Nigeria
```

and I'm trying to only prepend it to a specific h2 tag:

```
$('<h2>Test</h2>').prepend(table)
```

Not sure why its not working. Any idea why it's not prepending to the given h2 tag?

Comment: I don't think you can have a table inside an `h2` element.

Comment: that's what I'm having a problem with. I'm trying to append that script to <h2>Test</h2>. I wasn't sure how to approach it. I know I can append it to a specific class but am wanting to know if its possible to append it to the h2 tag

Comment: Do you mean `<h2>Test</h2><table>...</table>`?

Comment: Prepend means `<h2><table>...</table>Test</h2>`

Comment: correct: <h2>Test</h2><script>...</script>

Comment: either have it before the <h2>Test</h2> or after the <h2>Test</h2>

Comment: `$('<h2>Test</h2>').prepend(table)` needs to be inside an event such as onload, onchange etc. It won't run by itself. And semantically incorrect to have table inside a heading element but jQuery won't care.

Comment: Your operation is backwards.  `$('<h2>Test</h2>').prepend(table)` says, *Create a new h2 element, and then prepend the table to it.*  But that **h2** is not attached to the page.  So you are appending the table to it, but the h2 is never appended to the page, so the change is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code isn't working because you are using an improper jQuery selector to select your h2. the h2 needs to exist, either by coding it into your HTML, or adding it with JavaScript, you can then target it with jQuery with something like:

```
   <h2 id="foo">test</h2>

    // JS
    const table = '<table></table>';

    $('#foo').prepend(table);
```

working pen https://codepen.io/JustH/pen/gZeWNR

A separate issue is that a table inside an H2 is invalid and your browser will throw warnings

see [Why can’t I have a <table> inside an <h2>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808064/why-can-t-i-have-a-table-inside-an-h2)

if you are trying to just insert the table before or after the h2, then use the `.before` or `.after`

```
$('#foo').before(table);

// will result in:
<table></table>
<h2 id="foo">Test</h2>
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work by using:

$('h2:contains(Test)').before(table);

Answer (score 0):

`.prepend()` and `.append()` are for putting an element *inside* another element (either before or after the existing contents), but a table can't be inside a heading element. You should append each of them individually to the body:

```
$('body').append('<h2>Test</h2>', table);
```

Comment: $('h2:contains(Test)').before(table); seems to work for me.

Comment: Is the `<h2>` already in the DOM? I thought it was something you wanted to add. You wrote `$("<h2>Test</h2>")`, which is for creating a new element, not for selecting something.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to using jQuery Objects to improve your code. Example:

```js
var myData = "Name,City,Country\r\nWilliam,Yamrat,Nigeria";
/*
$.ajax({
  url: 'csv_data.csv',
  dataType: 'text',
}).done(successFunction);
*/
$(function() {
  function successFunction(data) {
    var allRows = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    var tbl = $("<table>");
    tbl.append($("<thead>"), $("<tbody>"));
    $.each(allRows, function(i, row) {
      var cells = row.split(",");
      console.log(row, cells);
      if (i == 0) {
        $("<tr>").appendTo($("thead", tbl));
        $.each(cells, function(k, v) {
          $("thead > tr", tbl).append($("<th>").html(v));
        });
      } else {
        var r = $("<tr>").appendTo($("tbody", tbl));
        $.each(cells, function(k, v) {
          r.append($("<td>").html(v));
        });
      }
    });
    console.log(tbl.prop("outerHTML"));
    $("h2:first").before(tbl);
  }

  successFunction(myData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Test</h2>
```

Suggest using `.before()` to append an element before the selector. If it's a specific `h2` element, it would be best to assign a unique ID or a specific Class to the element:

```
<h2 class="banner">Test</h2>
```

then use that to help append: `$(".banner")` otherwise you will append to all `h2` elements. The selector is the key.

Depending on how many table you make, you may consider moving this to a function:

```
function makeTable(r, h){
  var tbl = $("<table>");
  if(h == undefined){
    h = false;
  }
  if(h){
    tbl.append($("<thead>"));
  }
  tbl.append($("<tbody>"));
  $.each(r, function(i, row) {
    var cells = r.split(",");
    if (i == 0 && h) {
      $("<tr>").appendTo($("thead", tbl));
      $.each(cells, function(k, v) {
        $("thead > tr", tbl).append($("<th>").html(v));
      });
    } else {
      var tr = $("<tr>").appendTo($("tbody", tbl));
      $.each(cells, function(k, v) {
        tr.append($("<td>").html(v));
      });
    }
  });
  return tbl;
}
```

Then use like so:

```
var myTable = makeTable(allRows, true);
$("h2").before(myTable);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Two main things here. First, the H2 element does not exist at the time of "prepending". Second, it will make more sense replacing the whole thing, adding the H2 and the table at the same time. Other option, if you already have the H2 element, use jQuery .after, much easier.. http://api.jquery.com/after/